# AnyObjectで受け取った配列をキャストしてmapで処理する方法について

Tags: swift

Swiftで下記のコードのようにNSValueTransformerを使って値を変換しようとしています。

```
@objc (ImageTransformer)
class ImageTransformer: NSValueTransformer {
    override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject? {
        let tweets = value as? Array<Tweet>;
        return tweets.map { (tweet: Tweet) -> Tweet in
            // 処理
        };
    }
}
```

このとき、AnyObjectをArrayにキャストして処理したいのですが、

```
'Array<Tweet>' is not a subtype of 'Tweet'
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。
`Array<Tweet>`を`map`で処理しているので、引数には`Tweet`が入って来ると思っているのですが違うのでしょうか。
AnyObjectをキャストしてmapで処理する方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let tweets = value as? Array<Tweet>` を `if let tweets = value as? Array<Tweet>` にする以下の実装でエラーが起きないことを確認しました。

```
class ImageTransformer: NSValueTransformer {
    override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject? {
        if let tweets = value as? Array<Tweet> {
            return tweets.map{ (tweet: Tweet) -> Tweet in
                // 処理
                return tweet
            };
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

`AnyObject!` を `value as? Array<Tweet>` するところで `nil` が帰ってくる可能性があるために、コンパイラがエラーを吐いているのではと思っています。
再現のための最小コードは以下となります。

```
let tweets:Array<Tweet>? = nil
tweets.map{(tweet: Tweet) -> Tweet in
    // 処理
    return tweet
}
```